# Populate mvc dropdownlist based on user role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, dropdownlistfor

I'm adding a dropdown list to the view on my MVC project. The dropdown list will be populated based on the user type; a user can create a new user with the same or a lower access level. The access levels are based on the user 'role' assigned when the user is authenticated.
So for example, an administrator has the highest access level. He / she can create any user type, i.e.
Administrator
Manager
Supervisor
CSR
ReadOnly
A manager can create a manager, supervisor etc. (And so on.)
I have a 'Register' view where the user will enter the details to create a new user - username / password and access level. A dropdown list will give them the list of user types they can create.

My question is this: How should I **populate the dropdown list**? 
I have the logic in my controller and I create the dropdown list and pass it to the view. But the problem is, as expected - when 'Register' is clicked, the dropdown list will be lost.
I can create the dropdown list in the view, but is this 'best' practice? 
I have my code below for reference; any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

#### In the ViewModel:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User type")]
    public IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> UserType { get; set; }
}
```

#### View:

```
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserType, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserType, Model.UserType, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

#### In the controller:

```
 public ActionResult Register()
    {
        CSR.Models.ViewModels.Account.RegisterViewModel rvm = new CSR.Models.ViewModels.Account.RegisterViewModel();
        rvm.UserType = GetRoles();
        return View(rvm);
    }

 private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetRoles()
    {
        var roles = RolesList().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.accessLevelID.ToString(), Text = x.accessLevel });
        return new SelectList(roles, "Value", "Text");
    }
```

The RolesList() method returns a list of users based on **User.IsInRole**.

I am thinking the logic could be in the view so that the dropdown list is populated each time, but in my inexperienced opinion this seems to go against the 'MVC' pattern.
Advice is very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I've had discussions about this before with colleagues. Either you pass the DDL in the ViewModel or ViewBag (to each his preference - but be consistent in the same project). Your Controller should decide what the content of the DDL is, the View should only be concerned with rendering that list. At least, that's what we agreed on and it seems to us to be the correct way.

Comment: Thanks @Flater, I assumed that would be the case. The issue I have now though is ensuring the dropdownlist is not lost on a page refresh - each time the list items will need to be created according to the user role; and I guess I would have to re-create it each time!?!

Comment: In my case, I have written a sort of 'generic' dropdownlist for cases when you basically need all entities from a set (non-filtered, with a default binding). That means that I have preset FooDropdownlist, BarDropdownlist, ... controls. But in your case, you either have to reload it, store it in the Cache / Session data, or keep passing it back and forth (using hidden fields. It gets messy). I would suggest using the Session data here, since your list is specific to each user (at least to each authorization level). Or add the full list in the Cache, then filter it before passing it to the View.

Comment: Great, thanks very much @Flater. I will store it in the Session data; seems like the best option and would be what I have done before. Just not totally used to this environment so it's good to get advice / insight. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

1. Create ActionFilter PopulateUserRoles (this filter adds to ViewData[Constants.UserTypes] collection of items where Constants.UserTypes is string constant "UserTypes"); [example of such filter](https://bitbucket.org/maximtkachenko/mvcprototype/src/20e53fde1b9f603b594a92d57828d01cb677df75/PrototypeMvcSimple/Attributes/PopulateLetterTypesAttribute.cs) and you can inject inside filter everything you need
2. Decorate your Action by this attribute
3. Result:
   `[PopulateUserRoles]
   public ActionResult Register()...
   ...
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.UserType, ViewData[Constants.UserTypes]...`

   This option isn't required additional GetRoles() method in controller and additional IEnumerable UserType property in viewmodel. This option could be improved by using UIHint.

Comment: Thanks @oblomov. This is something I haven't seen before but looks like it could definitely work. I'm just a bit confused with the Constant.UserTypes and how this is set?! Sorry, this is all very new to me so struggling a bit!

Comment: @Misemefein It's simple constant string value which helps to avoid "magic strings" in view and actionfilter using ViewData.

Comment: I was searching good way to use dropdownlists and more complex controls in mvc. And my choice is UIHint (for complex fields in viewmodel: dropdownlists or some custom editor templates) + Editor template (which is used in UIHint) + Populate actionfilters.